# How to load a custom transformer in Spark 2.4

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a custom transformer in Spark 2.4.0. Saving it works fine. However, when I try to load it, I get the following error:

```scala
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: TestTransformer.<init>(java.lang.String)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader.load(ReadWrite.scala:496)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable$class.load(ReadWrite.scala:380)
  at TestTransformer$.load(<console>:40)
  ... 31 elided
```

This suggests to me that it can't find my transformer's constructor, which doesn't really make sense to me.

MCVE:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.{DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable, Identifiable}

class TestTransformer(override val uid: String) extends Transformer with DefaultParamsWritable{

    def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("TestTransformer"))

    override def transform(df: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
        val columns = df.columns
        df.select(columns.head, columns.tail: _*)
    }

    override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
        schema
    }

    override def copy(extra: ParamMap): TestTransformer = defaultCopy[TestTransformer](extra)
}

object TestTransformer extends DefaultParamsReadable[TestTransformer]{

    override def load(path: String): TestTransformer = super.load(path)

}

val transformer = new TestTransformer("test")

transformer.write.overwrite().save("test_transformer")
TestTransformer.load("test_transformer")
```

Running this (I'm using a Jupyter notebook) leads to the above error. I've tried compiling and running it as a .jar file, with no difference.

What puzzles me is that the equivalent PySpark code works fine:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
from pyspark.ml import Transformer
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable

class TestTransformer(Transformer, DefaultParamsWritable, DefaultParamsReadable):

    def transform(self, df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        return df

TestTransformer().save('test_transformer')
TestTransformer.load('test_transformer')
```

**How can I make a custom Spark transformer that can be saved and loaded?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem in spark-shell.

Trying to find the source of the problem I looked into `DefaultParamsReadable` and `DefaultParamsReader` sources and I could see they utilize Java reflection.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/ReadWrite.scala

lines 495-496

```
val instance =
    cls.getConstructor(classOf[String]).newInstance(metadata.uid).asInstanceOf[Params]
```

I think scala REPLs and Java reflection aren't good friends.

If you run this snippet (after yours):

```
new TestTransformer().getClass.getConstructors
```

you'll get the following output:

```
res1: Array[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_]] = Array(public TestTransformer($iw), public TestTransformer($iw,java.lang.String))
```

It is true! `TestTransformer.<init>(java.lang.String)` doesn't exist.

I found 2 workarounds,

1. Compiling your code with sbt and creating a jar, then including in spark-shell with `:require`, worked for me (You mentioned you tried a jar, I don't know how though)
2. Pasting the code in spark-shell with `:paste -raw` , worked fine as well. I suppose `-raw` prevents from REPL doing shenanigans to your classes. 
   See: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html

I'm not sure how you can adapt any of these to Jupyter but I hope this info is useful for you.

NOTE: I actually used spark-shell in spark 2.4.1

Comment: I'm quite new to Scala, so perhaps I didn't really do it right in a .jar (I have a lot more experience with Python and PySpark). Regarding your answer, I'll try it out tomorrow, thanks! I'm not sure if this is out of scope for this question, but do you know if this would also work on Spark 2.2 and 2.3?

Comment: What I did was creating a minimal sbt project and created the jar using `package` command.
And yes I'm pretty confident that the problem and the solution would be the same for 2.2 and 2.3 . In fact, I tested parts of the above in spark 2.3.2